# Replacing cells with cumulative count

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

is there a way to create a formula, that will cumulatively count cells with an `x` inside and output the result as a new range?

So this would be achieved:

[image]

It would also be completely fine if the cumulative count was in all cells (so the result would look like so):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A2:C2="x",COUNTIFS(A2:C2,A2:C2,COLUMN(A2:C2),"<="&COLUMN(A2:C2)),))`

which is a derived version of a formula in this tutorial:
https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/running-count-in-google-sheets/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're looking for the formula to go in cells A6:C9 - 
Put this formula into cell A6 and copy across/down:
`=COUNTA($A1:A1)`

If you want to specify the criteria for what increments the counter:
`=COUNTIF($A1:A1,"x")`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:C4="",,
 IF(A1:A4<>"", COLUMN(A:C), 
 IF(B1:B4<>"", COLUMN(A:C)-1, 
               COLUMN(A:C)-2))))
```

[image: 0]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:AI4="",,
 IF(A1:A4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI),    IF(B1:B4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-1, 
 IF(C1:C4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-2,  IF(D1:D4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-3,
 IF(E1:E4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-4,  IF(F1:F4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-5,
 IF(G1:G4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-6,  IF(H1:H4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-7,
 IF(I1:I4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-8,  IF(J1:J4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-9,
 IF(K1:K4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-10, IF(L1:L4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-11,
 IF(M1:M4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-12, IF(N1:N4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-13,
 IF(O1:O4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-14, IF(P1:P4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-15,
 IF(Q1:Q4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-16, IF(R1:R4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-17, 
 IF(S1:S4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-18, IF(T1:T4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-19,
 IF(U1:U4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-20, IF(V1:V4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-21,
 IF(W1:W4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-22, IF(X1:X4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-23,
 IF(Y1:Y4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-24, IF(Z1:Z4<>"",   COLUMN(A:AI)-25,
 IF(AA1:AA4<>"", COLUMN(A:AI)-26, IF(AB1:AB4<>"", COLUMN(A:AI)-27,
 IF(AC1:AC4<>"", COLUMN(A:AI)-28, IF(AD1:AD4<>"", COLUMN(A:AI)-29,
 IF(AE1:AE4<>"", COLUMN(A:AI)-30, IF(AF1:AF4<>"", COLUMN(A:AI)-31,
 IF(AG1:AG4<>"", COLUMN(A:AI)-32, IF(AH1:AH4<>"", COLUMN(A:AI)-33,
 COLUMN(A:AI)-34))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Nice with `arrayformula` solution, but in my real-world use case I have 35 columns, not just ABC - so I think this would get quite tedious to write out.